# Create a dynamic JSON with play

Tags: json, scala, rest, dynamic, playframework

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application using Reactivemongo driver (with Scala).
I've the recommendation.user collection that store all the user data.
One document has the following form:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("542e67e07f724fc2af28ba75"),
    "id" : "",
    "email" : "luigi@gmail.com",
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Liners - Baking Cups",
            "weight" : 2,
            "lastInsert" : 1412327492874
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - Jumbo",
            "weight" : 4,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597883569
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
            "weight" : 1,
            "lastInsert" : 1412327548205
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Fish:Swordfish Loin Portions",
            "weight" : 3,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597939124
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - alberto@gmail.com",
            "weight" : 2,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597939124
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i'm writing a method that returns all the tags of a particular user.
I return a JSOn responce.
In play how can i create a dynamic json??
My return json has the following form:

```
 {
       "tags": [
         {"tag": "tag1"},
         {"tag": "tag2"}
               ]
 }
```

This is my method implementation:

```
def userTag(user: String) = Action.async {
         //obtain all the users saved in the db.
         val allUser : Future[Option[User]] = Users.find(Json.obj("email" -> user)).one
         val futureComputation = allUser map {
                                        (user: Option[User]) =>
                                          user match {
                                            case Some(x) => x.tags  match {
                                              case Some(userTags) => val tags: List[Tag] =  userTags.map{tag: (Tag, Double, Long) => tag._1} //obtain all the Tag objects
                                               //here for every element in the tags variable i want to add it add the json.             
                                              case None => Ok(Json.obj()) //return an empty json.
                                            }
                                            case None => Ok(Json.obj()) //return an empty json
                                          }


         }
         futureComputation

     }
```

How can i solve my problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using:

```
def userTag(user: String) = Action.async {
         //obtain all the users saved in the db.
         val allUser : Future[Option[User]] = Users.find(Json.obj("email" -> user)).one
         val futureComputation = allUser map {
                                        (user: Option[User]) =>
                                          user match {
                                            case Some(x) => x.tags  match {
                                              case Some(userTags) => val tags =  userTags.map{tag: (Tag, Double, Long) => val t = tag._1; t.category + ":" + t.attr} //obtain all the Tag objects
                                                                                    val arrayTags = for(tag <- tags) yield{Json.obj("tag" -> tag)} //crete the array json
                                                                                    Ok(Json.obj("tags" -> arrayTags)) //return the json corresponding to the user.

                                              case None => Ok(Json.obj()) //return an empty json.
                                            }
                                            case None => Ok(Json.obj()) //return an empty json
                                          }


         }
         //return the Future computation JSON responce.
         futureComputation

     }
```